# Apache 2.4, .htaccess and php directive error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos8

I have upgraded to Centos 8, and find myself having to cope with the changes in Apache 2.4. I’ve started to get it working, but I have a perplexing error with a simple setting in `.htaccess`:

```
#   .htaccess
#   PHP Time Zone
    php_value date.timezone Australia/Melbourne
```

I get the dreaded error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

There’s no point contacting the server administrator because that’s me.

The `error_log` file has this:

> Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

This has always worked in the past on Apache 2.4, and also works when I use Apache 2.4 on XAMPP. So obviously there is something in some other configuration, possibly in `httpd.conf` which causes it to crash.

What setting am I missing, or should I change?

**Update**

As answered by @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana below, the solution lies in using the correct MPM. In my case, in the file `00-mpm-conf`:

- Comment out

  `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so`
- Uncomment

  `LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so`

For further information, see:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP
- https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39218

Comment: See the error_log  file. And just paste some of the latest output here.

Comment: Why not? It’s just there as a default, and the problem isn’t with the time zone setting itself.

Comment: You could just set it in the php.ini file anyways. See the error_log file. And just paste some of the latest output here.

Comment: Are you using php as a apache module? If you are using something like PHP-FPM you'll need to use php.ini files.

Comment: @EnricoDias You are right. I was about to say that https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: php_value is not working. Because PHP is not apache module in your case.

Comment: @EnricoDias I thought it was running as an Apache Module. Certainly it reads the `.htaccess` file, because when I comment out the directive, the problem goes away.

Comment: Which MPM are you using?

Comment: I don’t know about MPM. What is that?

Comment: You know, like mod_mpm_worker, mod_mpm_prefork, mod_mpm_event?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana This is the line from 00-mpm-conf: `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so`

Comment: When you are using either mod_mpm_event or mpm_mpm_worker instead of mod_mpm_prefork, you will not be able to use the PHP Module.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana That appears to have fixed it. Can you put the comment about `mod_mpm_prefork` into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using either mod_mpm_event or mod_mpm_worker instead of mod_mpm_prefork, you will not be able to use the PHP Module. This is because mod_mpm_event and mod_mpm_worker are threaded modules. And the PHP module is not thread safe.

If you are unsure how to do this, check out Soufiane ELH's tutorial which should be above/below this answer.

Comment: When I build httpd-2.4.46 I do not have the either `mod_mpm_event.so` or `mod_mpm_prefork.so` in the modules folder.  Does this mean the build went wrong?  Supposed to build from `prefork.c` in the server folder correct?

Comment: @Brian Wiley, What was your configure command?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219046/how-to-install-apache-2-4-46-from-source-on-ubuntu/65219058#65219058, see this answer, it might help you in someway

Comment: So I tried this first `./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-module=mpm-prefork --with-mpm=prefork` which should have worked based on the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html) and configure -h but then it had issue making 'mpm-prefork' (supposed to remove mod_ and replace underscores with -).  But it does work if you just remove `--with-module=mpm-prefork`.  So this should work for anybody else `./configure --with-mpm=prefork`

Comment: I am sure `--with-module=mpm-prefork` is invalid... Good job you fixed your issue.

Comment: Enable all mods to "reallyall" could work also probably.  I saw that option in the help also

Comment: I usually always use `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"` which I have mentioned on the link I sent two hours ago. This gives me the flexibility to edit and disable any modules any time.

Answer (score 1):

the event module is enabled by default on centos 8 .. to check wich module you have :

```
#sudo httpd -V | grep -i mpm
```

if you have enent module enabled, disable it, and enable the prefork module:

- Edit the /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf file
- Comment out the line for the event module
- uncomment the line for the prefork module
- restart apache

check again the module enabled by apache and you will find prefork :

```
# sudo httpd -V | grep -i mpm
Server MPM:     prefork
```

Comment: Nice job  on providing the tutorial.

Comment: Please note that it is the same tutorial for the worker module btw.