# How to install apache 2.4.46 from Source on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

How can I install Apache 2.4.46 in Ubuntu from source, because I want to have the pure package, without tweaks.

The apache2 installed from apt might be more secure, but this is my intention.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. You should attempt to first install it by following these instructions: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html (scroll to section `Installing from source`) and then if you have problems during compilation, ask the community for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note that you should always install the latest version of a software for more security. I suggest you to install Apache from Ubuntu's apt package manager 'if you are on a production server'. Installing it from source on a local environment doesn't matter. This tutorial is for Ubuntu/Debian based systems.**

Please follow this for the instructions of installing it, by me, with a bit more explanation. Go to the terminal, and enter the following commands one by one and hit enter for no confusion:

1. Install some required libraries:

   ```
    sudo apt install libnghttp2 libpcre3 libssl build-essential -y
   ```
2. Navigate to the directory from which we will be compiling apache.

   ```
    cd /usr/local/src
   ```
3. In your browser, go to http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi.
   Right click and copy the link location of the link looking like `Source: httpd-2.4.46.tar.gz`

   ```
    sudo wget -O- <download-link> | tar -zxf -
   ```
4. Also go to http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and copy the link location for `Unix Source: apr-1.7.0.tar.gz`

   ```
    sudo wget -O- <apr-download-link> | tar -zxf -
   ```
5. Go to http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and copy the link location for `Unix Source: apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz`

   ```
    sudo wget -O- <apr-util-download-link> | tar -zxf -
   ```
6. Move the downloaded and extracted apr files to the right location:
   sudo mv apr- httpd-/srclib/apr
7. Move the downloaded and extracted apr-util files to the right location:
   sudo mv apr-util- httpd-/srclib/apr-util
8. Navigate into the httpd directory:
   cd httpd-
9. According to me, this configuration is better than any other. The `--prefix` is where apache is installed.

   ```
    sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="reallyall" --enable-mpms-shared="all"
   ```
10. Compile the sources:
    sudo make
11. Install the compiled application to your system:
    sudo make install

These directories could be altered using different arguments in step **9.** (the `sudo ./configure` command)

The apache directory is `/usr/local/apache2`.
The apache conf directory is `/usr/local/apache2/conf`.
The apache main conf file is `/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.

For more info go to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it, please wait.

Comment: Have fun coding.

Comment: **I'm using 20.04 LTS focal.**  
I don't have _libssl_ and _libnghttp2_ listed in apt packages so I replaced them using _libssl-dev_ and _libnghttp2-dev_.  
  
All steps then go fine but the problem was when I check start of apache. It said I missed MPM modules. I added these lines (just at the head of LoadModule rows) in 'apache/conf/httpd.conf' file and I solved my problem.  
  
`LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so  
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so  
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so`